# MAZDA 3 2006 no compression?

Tags: speedometer, compression, timing-chain, vehicle-speed-sensor

Okay so I am in need of advice, I have a Mazda 3 2006, the timing chain was super stretched out which caused the car to die at a stop light or if the gas was not being pushed the car would die. So I replaced the timing chain in it, then started it up without the serpentine belt on it and it started fine. Once I put the serpentine belt on and tried start the car there is no compression? I also replaced the speed sensor because the speedometer and odometer would not work, that did not fix the problem as all?

Comment: These engines were keyless, how did you set the timing and are you sure that the engine didn't spin out of time?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How did you confirm you were getting "no compression"? Or do you mean the engine just isn't starting now?